# SQL: reference JOIN LEFT column in multiple joins

Tags: sql

Note: a common question is regarding how to do multiple joins in a dialect of SQL. This is not a question on *how* to do multiple joins, but *how* to reference a column in while joining

Suppose we have three tables:

1. `TABLE` x with columns (a, b, ...)
2. `TABLE` y with columns (b, c, ...)
3. `TABLE` z with columns (c, d, ...)

where columns a, b, and c are the keys to join on.

Then if we wanted to `CREATE TABLE` t for every record in `z` that can be mapped to column a in `x` we might try using sequential left joins (as we want to maintain every unique instance of a in x)

In two steps:

```
-- step 1
FROM (
  x
  LEFT JOIN y
  ON x.b = y.b
)

-- step 2
FROM (
  y
  LEFT JOIN z
  ON y.c = z.c
)
```

Trying to combine:

```
-- combined ?
FROM (
  -- step 1
  (
    x
    LEFT JOIN y
    ON x.b = y.b
  )
  -- step 2
  LEFT JOIN z
  ON ??.c = z.c
)
```

Since there is no direct key in table x to connect with z, can I still use `y.b` or do I need to use an alias e.g. step-1 `AS s1` and then `s1.b`?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Only tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: You should name any derived table and then you will be able to reference its columns: "FROM ... (x LEFT JOIN y ON x.b = y.b) [AS] XX ... ON XX.col = ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need nested queries or intermediate steps.

The standard solution is to just join the tables directly, following relationships, as follows :

```
SELECT x.a, x.b, z.c
FROM
    x
    LEFT JOIN y ON y.b = x.b
    LEFT JOIN z ON z.c = y.c
```

Hence you don't need to use column aliases.

Comment: @SumNeuron, which error are you getting ? Also, it would be good if you could post a complete SQL query so we can look at the whole thing

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near `'y ON y.b = x.b
  LEFT JOIN z ON z.c = y'` at line 4

Comment: What is the full SQL statement that you are executing @SumNeuron ?

Comment: `SLECT x.a, x.b, z.c FROM <your code>` (with a new line at each SQL statement)

Comment: @SumNeuron, I cannot see how this would generate a syntax error. Please check [this DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=byJmTqBzQ4)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185331/discussion-between-gmb-and-sumneuron).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you want:

```
FROM x LEFT JOIN
     y
     ON x.b = y.b LEFT JOIN
     z
     ON z.b = x.b
```

First, the `JOIN` operation is `LEFT JOIN`, not `JOIN LEFT`.

Second, you want to join on the `x` table.  Why?  You have a `LEFT JOIN` and non-matching rows in `y` will have a `y.b` value of `NULL`.  That's no so good for a `JOIN`.  So use the value in the first table.

EDIT:

For the revised question, you have no choice:

```
FROM x LEFT JOIN
     y
     ON x.b = y.b LEFT JOIN
     z
     ON z.c = y.c
```

I'm not sure what you are really asking.

Comment: I want to left join on `x` so that I have every value of `x`? also `z` doesn't have the column `b` hence the need for two joins?

Comment: @SumNeuron . . . In your second code example -- which is the basis for the question -- you are using the `b` column.  I don't understand the question if you are using `c`.  It is in only two tables, so you have to use those two tables.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo